# XSL template variable not printing

Tags: c#, xslt, .net-4.0

I don't know XSL templates very well as I only saw one for the first time two hours ago.

I have the following template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:FormData="ext:FormVal" 
     xmlns:FormUrl="ext:UrlFinder"                    
     >
  <xsl:param name="note"/>
  <xsl:param name="title"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>EW Email Notification- File Note insertion Failed</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>
          Failed to insert File note for form with refrence - <xsl:value-of select="FormData:get_RefFormId()" /> <br/>
          <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="FormUrl:get_RootUrl()"></xsl:value-of>FormAction/ViewForm?formId=<xsl:value-of select="FormData:get_FormId()"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>Click here </a> to open the form.
        </p>
        <p>
          Please insert this file note manually.
        </p>
        <p>
          <h3>
            Title:
          </h3>
          <out>          <xsl:value-of select="$title"></xsl:value-of>
          </out>

        </p>
        <p>
          <h3>
            Note:
          </h3>
         <xsl:value-of select="$note"></xsl:value-of>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Most of it was written by some one else. I added the `note` and `title` parameters. But, for some reason they are not showing up in the printed output.

However, `FormData:get_FormId()` works.

I am passing in the variables like this:

```
dictionary["note"] = note;
dictionary["title"] =title;
dictionary["ext:FormVal"] = formVal;
dictionary["ext:UrlFinder"] = urlFinder;
var objxslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

objxslt.Load(Helper.GetEmbeddedXmlResource(templateAssembly, templateName));

var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("DocumentRoot"));

XPathNavigator xpathnav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();
var xslarg = new XsltArgumentList();

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
{
    xslarg.AddExtensionObject(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value);
}

var emailbuilder = new StringBuilder();
var xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(emailbuilder));
objxslt.Transform(xpathnav, xslarg, xmlwriter, null);

var xemaildoc = new XmlDocument();
xemaildoc.LoadXml(emailbuilder.ToString());

XmlNode titlenode = xemaildoc.SelectSingleNode("//title");
string subjecttext = titlenode.InnerText;

XmlNode bodynode = xemaildoc.SelectSingleNode("//body");
string bodytext = bodynode.InnerXml;
```

The variable `bodytext` contains all the template but there are blanks where I expect the parameters to be printed.

Can anyone help me identify the reason why the `note` and `title` parameters are not showing up in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this is what I did. Instead of passing the strings `note` and `title` directly, I created a class:

```
public class InsertFileNoteContainer
{
    public String Note { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

And I put this in the dictionary with the key `ext:IFC`.

In the template I did:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:FormData="ext:FormVal" 
     xmlns:FormUrl="ext:UrlFinder" 
     xmlns:Container="ext:IFC"          
     >
```

and `<xsl:value-of select="Container:get_Title()"></xsl:value-of>`

and `<xsl:value-of select="Container:get_Note()"></xsl:value-of>`

Note that because I am new to XSL templates, I have no idea why this works. If any one can see why introducing a class here works where using string parameters failed, please let me know.